# How to apply data-mini="true" if the site is web (and not apply when it's on mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for my website, but the form elements are too big for a webpage. Is there a wa I can apply data-mini="true" for the entire site responsively? i.e apply mini for the website (> 768px) and not apply if screen width < 768px ?

I know I can apply individually but is there one place I can set that will be applicable to the entire set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apply the `.ui-mini` class to the body, besides some small glitches the jQuery Mobile CSS will do the rest.

You will find some small hotfixes inside the demo CSS below. For `flipswitches`, use the *checkbox* version.

**DEMO:** ([Forms gallery](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/forms-gallery/))

```js
function miniUI(e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("ui-mini", window.innerWidth > 768);
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on("throttledresize", function(e) {
    miniUI(e);
  });
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) {
  miniUI(e);
});
```

```css
/* Hotfix for mixed controlgroup buttons */
.ui-mini .ui-btn {
  font-size: inherit !important;
}

/* Hotfix for sliders */
.ui-mini .ui-slider .ui-slider-track,
.ui-mini .ui-rangeslider .ui-slider-track {
  height: 12px !important;
  top: 8px !important;
}
.ui-mini .ui-slider .ui-slider-track .ui-slider-handle,
.ui-mini .ui-rangeslider .ui-slider-track .ui-slider-handle{
  height: 14px !important;
  width: 14px !important;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -8px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h2>Responsive Mini</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <label for="textinput-2">Text Input:</label>
      <input type="text" name="textinput-2" id="textinput-2" placeholder="Text input" value="">
      <label for="search-2">Search Input:</label>
      <input type="search" name="search-2" id="search-2" value="">
      <label for="textarea-2">Textarea:</label>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-2" id="textarea-2">Textarea</textarea>
      <label for="select-native-2">Native select:</label>
      <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2">
          <option value="small">One</option>
          <option value="medium">Two</option>
          <option value="large">Three</option>
      </select>
      <label for="select-multiple-2">Custom multiple select:</label>
      <select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" name="select-multiple-2" id="select-multiple-2">
          <option value="">Choices:</option>
          <option value="small">One</option>
          <option value="medium">Two</option>
          <option value="large">Three</option>
      </select>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Vertical controlgroup, buttons:</legend>
          <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right">One</button>
          <input type="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" value="Two">
          <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-right">Three</a>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Horizontal controlgroup, buttons:</legend>
          <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-right">One</button>
          <input type="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" value="Two">
          <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-right">Three</a>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Vertical controlgroup, select:</legend>
          <label for="select-v-2a">Select A</label>
          <select name="select-v-2a" id="select-v-2a">
              <option value="#">One</option>
              <option value="#">Two</option>
              <option value="#">Three</option>
          </select>
          <label for="select-v-2b">Select B</label>
          <select name="select-v-2b" id="select-v-2b">
              <option value="#">One</option>
              <option value="#">Two</option>
              <option value="#">Three</option>
          </select>
          <label for="select-v-2c">Select C</label>
          <select name="select-v-2c" id="select-v-2c">
              <option value="#">One</option>
              <option value="#">Two</option>
              <option value="#">Three</option>
          </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Horizontal controlgroup, mixed:</legend>
          <a href="#" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">Link</a>
          <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext">Button</button>
          <label for="select-v-2e">Select</label>
          <select name="select-v-2e" id="select-v-2e">
              <option value="#">One</option>
              <option value="#">Two</option>
              <option value="#">Three</option>
          </select>
      </fieldset>
      <label for="slider-2">Slider:</label>
      <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true">
      <div data-role="rangeslider">
          <label for="range-1a">Rangeslider:</label>
          <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40">
          <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
          <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80">
      </div>
      <div data-role="rangeslider">
          <label for="range-1a">Rangeslider:</label>
          <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40">
          <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
          <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80">
      </div>
      <fieldset>
      <label for="checkbox-based-flipswitch">Checkbox-based:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Single checkbox:</legend>
          <label for="checkbox-2">I agree</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Vertical controlgroup, checkbox:</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
          <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Vertical controlgroup, radio:</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="on" checked="checked">
          <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">One</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="off">
          <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">Two</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="other">
          <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">Three</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Horizontal controlgroup, checkbox:</legend>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a">
          <label for="checkbox-h-2a">One</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2b" id="checkbox-h-2b">
          <label for="checkbox-h-2b">Two</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2c" id="checkbox-h-2c">
          <label for="checkbox-h-2c">Three</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Horizontal controlgroup, radio:</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">One</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Two</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="other">
          <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Three</label>
      </fieldset>
      <label for="submit-2">Send:</label>
      <button class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" type="submit" id="submit-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
      <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Show the snippet in *fullpage* to see the difference.